# Why DomPDF inserts a blank page and cuts content

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using Codeigniter with DomPDF and it usually works well, but there is a case when it inserts blank pages and cuts the content that follows. I have noticed that this happens when I have `<i>` or `<b>` tags inside a chunk of text that contains consecutive `<br />` tags. For example, take this structure:

```
<p>some text <i>some text<br /><br />some text ... </i></p>
```

ends up inserting blank pages and cutting content.

The code outputting the content is:

```
...
<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>

<?php foreach ($entries as $entry) { ?>

    <p><?php echo nl2br(str_replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;", $entry['description'])); ?></p>   

<?php } ?>

<p><?php echo $copyrightmessage ?></p>

<div style="page-break-before:always;width:100%;text-align:center;">

    <div style="height:100px;"></div>

    <img src="writerbig.png" />
    <br />
</div>
...
```

Here is sample HTML that to reproduce the issue:

```
To better understand why this course of action was necessary, 
A'th'n learned why<br /> <br /> it was the responsibility, shame of each of the incarnations for ridding this 
world of<br /> <br /> this threat.<br /> <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; H'br'a, spoken 
through A'yd'a, explained the CHTHONIAN collective and why, since<br /> <br /> A'yd'a through T'li'a, H'br'a, now, A'th'n it had to come to this point.<br /> <br /> <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<i>Since her initial landfall, every time that the Primae had released a life force<br /> <br /> from a body she 
killed, this being the only logical solution to correct the crisis,<br /> <br /> the spirit had nowhere to go. <br /> 
<br /> It hung in the ether seeking spiritual release. Never finding any, the spirits soon <br /> <br /> learned that 
joining together made them capable of<br /> <br /> creating entities that could exist, again, in the living world, 
albeit as Sapen<br /> <br /> mockeries. <br /> <br /> Learning swiftly, the collected spirits came to the 
realization that not<br /> <br /> only could they exist on the living plane they could alter it.<br /> <br /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; It was this "awakening" that started their raiding, terrorizing, 
destroying all<br /> <br /> living beings they encountered.<br /> <br /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; The end result of their intermingling was to, first, confuse, next, 
annihilate<br /> <br /> the outer husks of the tortured to absorb them into their collective existence.<br /> <br 
/> <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; In time, the first few spirits realized they were capable of 
manipulation,<br /> <br /> allowing them to become very adept at their methods with the one goal being 
total<br /> <br /> domination of all species, races.<br /> <br /> Keeping their combined numbers small enabled 
them to become the most powerful psychic <br /> <br /> entities ever created.<br /> <br /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; The more powerful, the collective became the more notice the 
Primae took of them.<br /> <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Within a few life cycles, the 
Primae realized it was her responsibility to end<br /> <br /> this threat. However, the collective was always one 
step ahead, they knew that if the<br /> <br /> Primae caught them, she would release them back, unwillingly, 
into the spirit world<br /> <br /> where they would soon disperse into eternity.<br /> <br /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This evasion continued until H'br'a, who was a greater Primae then 
ever before,<br /> <br /> since she was a hybrid of two species, Sapen and Floar. It was this species melding<br 
/> <br /> that prevented the collective from manipulating her mind.<br /> <br /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; H'br'a would have succeeded, in totally eradicating the collective 
that all the<br /> <br /> previous incarnations had attempted, except two had been on a raid, when she 
arrived.<br /> <br /> Before H'br'a had the opportunity to complete the spiritual release, she had<br /> <br /> 
received her next to last tattoo that triggered her action to seek out her successor.<br /> <br /> All following 
actions lead to her capture by the Levians until she was rescued<br /> <br /> and reborn as A'th'n.<br /> <br /> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Now it was up to A'th'n, a further enhanced incarnation, who, 
because of&nbsp;&nbsp;her<br /> <br /> being an older Primae incarnation and her physical differences, made 
her immune to the<br /> <br /> CHTHONIAN collective influence.<br /> <br /> Her untried plan with F'lisa, 
hopefully, would be the solution.</i><br /><br /><br />
```

Each entry contains plain text except optionally some `<i>` and `<b>` tags (properly nested).
If I remove the `<i>` tags from the entry, it formats perfectly.

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: It would help to see the HTML, not the PHP that generates the HTML. I am unable to duplicate the issue with the simple code you've posted. Also, which version of dompdf are you using?

Comment: Hi @BrianS , I have edited the question to add the HTML that actually breaks. Please let me know if you can reproduce the issue. I am using the latest version (just downloaded it from GitHub

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem lies, but dompdf is definitely having trouble with this text. Could be an issue around celements and paging. I don't really have a good solution right now except to isolate each line into its own DIV element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with writing a script to de-nest HTML prior printing the PDF file.

I did something like:

find all `<br />` tags between `<i></i>` tags and replace them with `</i><br /><i>`

I know that this approach would not scale well given if any combination of nested HTML tags was possible, but in my case, the tags were limited to `<br>`, `<i>` and `<b>`

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone

Answer (score 0):

Nested tags and DomPDF are not good friends. You can try with  and  fonts and if that doesn't work, try replacing them with spans.

Maybe the problem is in some page break. If the page breaks when a tag is open, it will break the whole PDF.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. dompdf is able to handle nested tags fine. There are certain issues that could be problematic, but I don't think "nested tags" is the issue here.